# Why must the file exist when using the 'r+' mode in fopen?

Tags: c++, c, fopen

Why add this constraint when your intentions are to both read and write data to the file?

My application wants to open the file in both reading an writing mode. If I use `w+` it will destroy the previous contests of the file, but at the same time it will create the file if it doesn't exist.

However if I use the `r+` mode, my application will work properly, but if the file doesn't exist it will throw an exception about the nonexistence of the file.

Comment: Because if it doesn't exist the program has nowhere to read from? Isn't it logical? And it would be absurd to create a new blank file just to read from it

Comment: @Igor ,Title and first sentence

Comment: Read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/)

Comment: Have you tried opening the file as "rw+"?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews AFAIK the "rw+" mode doesn't exist.

Comment: My bad, "rw+" combination doesn't exist.  However, "a+" does.  The "a+" option opens the file for read and write; if the file exists, the file position pointer is set to the end for appending.

Comment: perhaps just because 'r' means reading and creating a file is just not a read only action. try a+ even you read only on it.

Comment: can you do fseeks with `a+` and write bytes in specific locations inside the file? because for some reason my application fails with this option.

Comment: Michael Waltz link explain that : with a+ read operation can be repositionned , while write action will always be done at end and fflush should be use in between

Comment: thanks for the comments and the answer. What I learned from this discussion is that I should never assume anything about anything prior to reading the official specification very carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this. If the first fopen fails because the file does not exist, the second fopen will try to create it. If the second fopen fails there are serious problems.

```
if((fp = fopen("filename","r+")) == NULL) {
    if((fp = fopen("filename","w+")) == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: D'oh - I must have missed the == NULLs, sorry.